# unable to return the corrrect variable in a c function

Tags: c

I want this program to keep track of the number of cycles that the user enters a value, the program is running all well but the function `cycler()` is not returning the appropriate value. I would be grateful for anyone who would help me here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cycle=0;

int main()
{
    startProgram(0);//If status is 1, the program will exit
    return 0;
}

void startProgram(int status) {
    if (status == 0) {

        printf("Enter a value\n");
        int input;
        scanf("%d",&input);
        printf("input is: %d\n",input);

        /*
           Here is where i need help!!!!!!!!!!
           When the cycler() is called, i want it to pass in the value of current cycle,
           The value of cycle has first been initialized to 0  
        */
        int cycle = cycler(cycle); 

        printf("Cycle Number : %d\n",cycle);

        resetProgram(input);

    } else {
        printf("Exiting");
    }
}

int cycler(int x){
    int ret = x++;
    return ret;
}

void resetProgram(int status){
    if ((status > 0) && (status < 12)) {
        startProgram(0);
    } else {
        printf("\nExit\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int cycle=cycler(cycle);` lose the `int`, you're declaring a new variable, not using the global one

Comment: What is the user input and what is the expected output?

Comment: You probably want to restructure your program to avoid the mutual recursion.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but the `cycler` function does nothing really useful, why not just write `cycle++` instead of `cycle = cycler(cycle);`? Or is the `cycler` function just a stub?

Comment: What they said ^^ (mutual recursion) except you probably don't understand those words. What that means is that `startProgram` is calling `resetProgram` which is then calling `startProgram` again. That's not great (research "call stack" if you want to learn why). A better way would be to allow resetProgram to return, and put the code in `startProgram` in a loop structure, like a `while` or `for` loop.

Comment: What it all boils down to: you can't do programming by trial and error. You must know what everything you write actually does. There's no such thing as "lets try this and see if it works". Thus: get a good C programming book and read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing exactly what output you expect, but I *think* you're wanting the "cycle number" to increase each time it is called. If that's the case, then you need some way of tracking the previous value of the variable. There are a few ways of doing this, but it's hard to prescribe the "right" way, when there are some glaring mistakes in the structure of your code itself.

The big mistake here is the "mutual recursion" which was mentioned in one of the comments. Imagine you have two functions, like so

```
void a()
{
    // do something
    b();
}

void b()
{
    // do something
    a();
}
```

You can see here that `a` calls `b`, and `b` calls `a`. This program will repeat forever. The problem is, that every time a function is called in C, a bit of memory is allocated in ram, to keep track of what function you're in. Since neither `a` or `b` is allowed to end, or, more formally, to "`return`", that memory is never deallocated. This program will eventually run out of memory and crash. (It might not actually, because of something called "inlining", but that's just because this is a contrived example.)

A better way to do this in C is to use a `while` or `for` loop.

```
void a()
{
    // do something
}

void b()
{
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        a()
        b()
    }
}
```

`while` loops will continue to repeat, as long as the value inside the parentheses is not `0`. Since the value (`1`) will never be `0`, this structure will loop forever, and does not have the same problem with mutual recursion, as `a` and `b` are both allowed to end, and therefore their memory will be deallocated after each call.

So to fix the problem you actually asked about, one could introduce `static` variables, as suggested (correctly) in another answer, or one could restructure their code not to require them. I prefer the following approach, where `startProgram()` is only called once, and therefore there is no need for `cycle` to be static.

```
void startProgram()
{
    int statusIsGood = 1;
    int cycle = 1;

    while(statusIsGood)
    {
        int input;

        scanf("%d", &input);

        statusIsGood = getStatus(input);

        printf("Cycle count: %d", cycle);

        // In practice, it makes more sense to simply do
        // cycle++; and get rid of `nextCycle()` all together
        cycle = nextCycle();
    }
}

int nextCycle(int cycle)
{
    return cycle + 1;
}

int getStatus(int input)
{
    if (input <= 0 || input >= 12)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello, your comment really taught me alot of staff i never knew, mutual recursion was a new thing i didnt actually know.. i apprecate you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already declared `cycle` as a global variable, the best way to keep count of the number of cycles is doing `cycle++`.

Comment: He has already declared `cycle` as a global variable. and he is using that variable inside `cycler` function. It is preserved in his code. I think the issue is something else.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `x++` in `cycler()` do `++x`.

The issue with `int ret = x++;` is that it is returning the value of x **before** incrementing it. and then `ret` is returned with the same value (which is not incremented).

Suppose `x` is `0`. 0 is the initial `cycle` value.

After the statement `int ret = x++;` x will increase to 1 but `ret` will be assigned with 0 ( still the old value) and this `0` will be returned.

The above event will happen everytime.

There is one more issue: You have defined `cycle` 2 times: globally and locally. I think you should remove  `int` before `int cycle = cycler(cycle);`

Comment: Fundamental difference between postfix and prefix operator

Comment: Yes, but it's not only that.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `int cycle` again in `startProgram()` is causing problems

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cycle=0;
void resetProgram(int status);
int cycler(int *x){
    return *x+1;
}

void startProgram(int status) {
    if (status == 0) {

        printf("Enter a value\n");
        int input;
        scanf("%d",&input);
        printf("input is: %d\n",input);

        /*
           Here is where i need help!!!!!!!!!!
           When the cycler() is called, i want it to pass in the value of current cycle,
           The value of cycle has first been initialized to 0  
        */
        //in your code you declared cycle again local variable was given priority
        cycle = cycler(&cycle); 

        printf("Cycle Number : %d\n",cycle);

        resetProgram(input);

    } else {
        printf("Exiting");
    }
}

void resetProgram(int status){
    if ((status > 0) && (status < 12)) {
        startProgram(0);
    } else {
        printf("\nExit\n");
    }
}




int main()
{
    startProgram(0);//If status is 1, the program will exit
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: double declaration of int cycle globally and locally is causing problem. I just added comment. I am new to stack overflow. Any suggestions or edits in my answers would be appreciated so that I can improve them in future.

Comment: Federico klez Culloca got the answer in comment.Thanks for edits.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you mean Counter instead of Cycler. That's a common data structure that counts occurrences of something. You can just use an `int` variable for that, but I would rather define a structure for it. This allows you to have a "black box" counter that only has a few defined operations. In this case that would be "count up", and "get" to see the current value of the counter.

The code for this is:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} Counter;

void counter_init(Counter *ctr) {
    ctr->value = 0;
}

void counter_up(Counter *ctr) {
    ctr->value++;
}

int counter_get(const Counter *ctr) {
    return ctr->value;
}
```

This may look like a lot of code, but it's worth it. One nice thing is that you no longer declare an `int` variable (which could basically be used for anything: calculations, counting, ID, file descriptor) but a `Counter` variable, and this definition already states the exact purpose of that variable.

```
Counter ctr;
counter_init(&ctr);

while (fgetc(stdin) != EOF) {
    counter_up(&ctr);
}

printf("You entered %d bytes.\n", counter_get(&ctr));
```

This program clearly expresses its intention of counting something, in this case the length of the input. Plus, it's not possible to accidentally modify the counter's value in unintended ways.

The plain `int` version of the code is:

```
int ctr = 0;

while (fgetc(stdin) != EOF) {
    ctr++;
}

printf("You entered %d bytes.\n", ctr);
```

The difference is that if you pass that counter around so that another function can modify it, that function's parameter is `int *ctr`, and the type `int *` doesn't express much. It could be a pointer to a single int, or to an array of ints. Having a `Counter *ctr` parameter makes the intention very clear.

Whether the situation is worth this overhead of defining a custom data type is a choice you have to make. For each situation individually.

Comment: This is insane. Do we need to throw away for loops with "naked" `int`s because counters are too dangerous now?

Comment: And it is _definitely_ possible to modify the counter in an unintended way. Try `counter.value = 300`.

Comment: @MichaelDorst It is not possible to _accidentally_ modify the counter. Of course you can `*((int*)ctr)*=2`, but that's definitely not accidentally.